# What does this instruction in the Bundler setup mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to setup Bundler with Rails 2.3.10 to make the transition to Rails 3 easier. But I'm not sure what the instruction on [this page](http://gembundler.com/bundler_setup.html) means. Am I supposed to require all the gems that I'm using in my app? If so, where? Thanks for reading.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the Rails 2.3 tutorial http://gembundler.com/rails23.html it's better on your case.

The setup made all requirement of all gem in your Gemfile. He avoid to do a lot of require ''.